# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, itms-90809

i've this:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 12 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.12.1) : 0.7.0
   native-run (update available: 1.0.0)   : 0.3.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.4
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.4 Build version 11E146
```

This my ionic plugin list

```
com.adjust.sdk 4.14.0 "Adjust"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 3.2.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-firebase-lib 4.0.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.2.2 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.5.1 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.6.0 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

This nom ouate

```
Package                                 Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
@angular/animations                      5.2.11  5.2.11   9.1.2  App
@angular/common                          5.2.11  5.2.11   9.1.2  App
@angular/compiler                        5.2.11  5.2.11   9.1.2  App
@angular/compiler-cli                    5.2.11  5.2.11   9.1.2  App
@angular/core                            5.2.11  5.2.11   9.1.2  App
@angular/forms                           5.2.11  5.2.11   9.1.2  App
@angular/http                            5.2.11  5.2.11  7.2.16  App
@angular/platform-browser                5.2.11  5.2.11   9.1.2  App
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic        5.2.11  5.2.11   9.1.2  App
@ionic-native/core                       4.15.0  4.15.0  5.24.0  App
@ionic-native/facebook                   4.17.0  4.17.0  5.24.0  App
@ionic-native/geolocation                4.20.0  4.20.0  5.24.0  App
@ionic-native/in-app-browser             5.23.0  5.24.0  5.24.0  App
@ionic-native/native-geocoder            4.20.0  4.20.0  5.24.0  App
@ionic-native/onesignal                  4.20.0  4.20.0  5.24.0  App
@ionic-native/splash-screen              4.15.0  4.15.0  5.24.0  App
@ionic-native/status-bar                 4.15.0  4.15.0  5.24.0  App
@ionic/lab                               1.0.13  1.0.13   3.1.3  App
@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2              6.0.1   6.0.1   8.1.0  App
ajv                                       5.5.2   5.5.2  6.12.0  App
ajv-keywords                              2.1.1   2.1.1   3.4.1  App
cordova-android-support-gradle-release    2.1.0   2.1.0   3.0.1  App
cordova-plugin-firebase-lib               4.1.0   4.1.0   5.1.1  App
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview              4.1.0   4.1.0   4.2.0  App
cordova-sqlite-storage                    2.6.0   2.6.0   5.0.0  App
ionic-angular                             3.9.2   3.9.2  3.9.10  App
ionicons                                  3.0.0   3.0.0   5.0.1  App
jetifier                                  1.6.4   1.6.5   1.6.5  App
leaflet                                   1.4.0   1.6.0   1.6.0  App
onesignal-cordova-plugin                  2.6.0   2.9.0   2.9.0  App
pacote                                    9.5.0  9.5.12  11.1.4  App
rxjs                                     5.5.11  5.5.11   6.5.5  App
tsickle                                  0.27.5  0.27.5  0.38.1  App
typescript                                2.6.2   2.9.2   3.8.3  App
zone.js                                  0.8.26  0.8.26  0.10.3  App
```

In my config.xml (and config of platform/iOS) - under widget

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
   <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

But I've this error

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will no longer accept submissions of new apps that use UIWebView as of April 30, 2020 and app updates that use UIWebView as of December 2020. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Comment: Did you try excluding particular plugins that you suspect? like starting with in app browser? I mean purely for finding the issue.

Comment: Could you please tell us how you solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

Check the CordovaLib target -> Build Stettings -> User Defined (very bottom) of your project. There you find `WK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY = 0` set this to `WK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY = 1` Setting the macro via GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS does not work. You can also search for WK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY with Xcode and it will display quickly if the Flag is set to 0.

This flag will be changed by Cordova only if the configure.xml contains `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />` **at the time you create a new ios project**. So this preference is pretty strange.

There still may be other sources for your problem, but that worked for me.

Comment: Despite applying these changes my app still got rejected...